# PERCENTILE_CONT() in redshift

Tags: sql, function, amazon-redshift, typecasting-operator

I am firing a query which is using PERCENTILE_CONT() function, Something like:

```
select .....
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.90) within group (order by END_DATE-START_DATE)
from ....
where .....
;
```

Now This query completely works fine when I fire it from SQLDeveloper in Oracle DB, but for some reason, I need to use RedShift data base and when I fire above query in it, it is throwing an error like:

```
ERROR: function percentile_cont(interval, numeric) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.`
```

As suggested, I tried to use typecast to DECIMAL and INTEGER type but I am getting the same error.

I have searched documentation, but I couldn't find a solution from there too.
Any thoughts, why?

P.S: Not able to put tag PERCENTILE_CONT as it is having less reputation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this work?

```
   PERCENTILE_CONT(0.90) within group (order by datediff(day, START_DATE, END_DATE)
```

I am guessing that the problem is the date difference.

Comment: I used the datediff function as you suggested, but it came up with new error, then I used another version of datediff i.e. datediff(END_DATE,  START_DATE) but this is throwing a new error that ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 635. By putting some mistakes at every random line, I identified that error is on that line only where I am using this group(order by...) function. Completely clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out !

```
 percentile_cont(0.90) within group 
((order by datediff(day, START_DATE, END_DATE)::INT4 desc) over()
```